# CSL - How can I italicise the publisher in just two kinds of reference?

Tags: csl, font-style

We have been editing an existing referencing style to customise it so our needs, and I need to make it so that article journals reports have the publisher in italics, but that no other kinds of reference do. Is there a way to do it?
We're using ReadCube Papers and the CSL Code Editor at citationstyles.org
I've been trying to do conditionals but I think my knowledge is not there yet.

Comment: Definitely doable. Could you provide a bit more detail? Ideally, a link to you current style code, but at a minimum, the exact format you want the references for a journal article and some other item with a publisher (book, chapter, e.g.) to look like.